# emacs ediff show all buffer diff word-wise (like vimdiff)

Tags: themes, ediff, diff

**Issue description**

When launching Ediff color scheme is very poor and i do not have word wise diff highlight. It seems that diff color faces are not activated at ediff startup.

I use `emacs -Q` to avoid installed themes interference.

But as you can see, down the pic, `Auto-refining is ON` and hitting `*` has no change.

[image]

**Workaround**

Fólkvangr provided a working solution : the `j` key magically highlight the buffer with great colors and show word wise diff.

[image]

**What i'm expecting**

I would like diff to open like on the second picture by default AND show all differences of the buffer - not only by chunks ( where you have to type `j`, then `n` / `p` to sequentially move to chunks).

**Broadly, I'd like it to display vertical side by side files with all diff highlighted at character level the way vimdiff and vscode do.**

Here is my ediff config made of things i read and the gnu doc :

```
;; turn off whitespace checking:
(setq ediff-diff-options "-w")
;; side by side diff
(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally)
;; ne pas ouvrir de fenêtre séparée pour les contrôles :
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
;; refinement:
(setq-default ediff-forward-word-function 'forward-char)
```

Comment: You've posted two separate questions in one post. Can you split it up?

Comment: Well, i am sure those are really connected and are very probably one problem. Describing those two issues should help to grasp what's wrong. But I will do that if no one pick it up that way.

Comment: There are at least 2 questions here. Please separate them.

Comment: Ok, done. Sibling issue is https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50889/word-wise-refined-highlight-diff-inside-word

Comment: I added a screenshot. As you can see, auto-refining is ON, and we cannot see the in word diff on '11' changed to '22'. Theme is Kaolin dark valley. But same pb with other themes. Kaolin themes look serious and they have color schemes associated with diff.

Comment: Woww! The `j` key makes it work right away :-) !!! In Magit too!!! How can it be activated by default for the whole ediff ? The link up my post brings you to another related issue where i wrote my ediff emacs file config. Thanksss!

Comment: @stockersky you might check if `ediff-auto-refine` is set to 'on'; also see `magit-diff-refine-hunk`

Comment: @amitp I added elements in my config related to ediff. I think the 2 last instructions are related to your advice.

Comment: Your question is too broad, rambling, and now evolving ("Now, things is to make it a default behavior"). The aim is specific, how-to questions and separate specific, how-to answers. Keep in mind that comments can be deleted at any time. It's not about an evolving discussion; it's about Q&A. Please try to clean up your question, and perhaps post a specific answer for it. Otherwise it risks being deleted. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I edited the question to narrow what is expected. And also deleted the duplicated question.

Comment: @Fólkvangr tak! You mean, that you have to step through a region with the `j` to trigger the word-wise highlighting? Actually, i noticed that, on a bigger file (like my init.el), only the first differences are properly highlighted when using the `j` key... I have seen screen-casts where their whole screen if all diff flashy right out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `ediff` displays line-based difference regions like `diff`. However, refinements are displayed using the moving commands like <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>.

> #### Ediff manual
>
> The functions `ediff-files`, `ediff-buffers`, `ediff-files3`, `ediff-buffers3` first display the coarse, line-based difference regions, as reported by the `diff` program.
>
> [...] the differences are highlighted as you step through them.

<sub>Edit: differences are probably highlighted consecutively because Ediff is an interactive application: "the user browses through the differences".</sub>

Comment: Yes, sounds like this is a default behavior. Even magit have the config `magit-diff-refine-hunk all` but it does only apply to magit-diff and not to magit-Ediff. Today, computers should really be able to handle this overload! At least, it could be great to to able to specify a treshold (ex: number of lines in the buffer) to activate the whole buffer word-wise refinement. Or maybe code some EmacsLisp to implement it. But I'm not comfortable with it yet. Anyway, I'm getting used to it and rarely use another app to review my changes before committing.